# Replace Dictionary Values with Lists

Tags: python, list, dictionary, iteration

For the given dictionary, an unchanged_key and a list(assuming list will always have text-1 elements) What is the easiest way to replace all the values in dictionary except unchanged_key ('a') from the list ro.

```
text = {'a': [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], 'b': [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0], 'c': [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1], 'd': [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1]}
unchanged_key = 'a'
ro = [[1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Output:

```
text = {'a': [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], 'b': [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1], 'c': [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0], 'd': [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]}
```

Comment: This will just give out a list of all the values in dictionary right?

Comment: Plain `dict`s are not ordered structures. If you want to impose an ordering, use a list of tuples. If you want to impose an ordering but have `O(1)` lookups, use an `OrderedDict`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want the order of replacement as same as the order in the list 'ro'. However, if the key 'a' comes somewhere in middle of dict 'text', its questionable.
You can do as below, which works out:

```
text = {'a': [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], 'b': [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0], 'c': [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1], 'd': [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1]}
unchanged_key = 'a'
ro = [[1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]]
ind=-1
for k,v in text.items():    #iterating thru dictionary 'text'  
    if k==unchanged_key:
        pass
    else:
        ind=ind+1
        text[k]=ro[ind]    #repl;acing the values from ro
```

> Output: ('text' dictionary)
>   {'a':[1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], 'b':[1, 0, 1, 0,
>   1, 1], 'c':[1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0], 'd':[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]}

Comment: I just could come up with something similar on a sandbox and then I see your solution:
unchanged_key = 'a'
r = 0
for i in text.keys():
    if i == unchanged_key : continue
    text[i] = ro[r]
    r = r + 1

Thank you!